# VBA Application.Caller runtime error

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error

I have the following code in VBA:

```
Sub Kontrollkästchen_KlickenSieAuf()
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Hinterlegungsmatrix Auswahl")
Dim i, j, rowx, columnx As Integer
rowx = Application.Caller.row 'I got here the run time error (object required)-->.row doesn't work
columnx = Application.Caller.column 'I got here the run time error (object required)-->.column doesn't work
        If Worksheets("Hinterlegungsmatrix Auswahl").Cells(rowx, columnx).Value = True Then
              For i = 6 To 22
                For j = 3 To 22
                    If (Worksheets("Hinterlegungsmatrix Auswahl").Cells(i, j).Interior.Color = RGB(250, 192, 144)) Or (Worksheets("Hinterlegungsmatrix Auswahl").Cells(i, j).Interior.Color = RGB(83, 142, 213)) Or (Worksheets("Hinterlegungsmatrix Auswahl").Cells(i, j).Interior.Color = RGB(242, 221, 220)) Then
                      Worksheets("Hinterlegungsmatrix Auswahl").Cells(i, j).Value = True
                    End If
                Next j
            Next i
        End If
End With
End Sub
```

I would like to get the Cell where the Checkbox is activated, but it throws a run time error, wenn I use Application.Caller.Address or .Row or .Column.
I assigned the checkbox the sub Kontrollkästchen_KlickenSieAuf()
I would be very happy, if someone can help me.

Greets

Comment: Maybe you could tell us what you are trying to do because `Application.Caller` only works from UDFs and you seem to be trying to call it from a Sub procedure

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer. I would like to find the cell, where the checkbox is clicked on, this means the row and the column. The problem is that I have about 30 checkboxes and I would only write 1 sub for all of them, means assign the checkboxes to the sub.

Comment: Do you mean the cell _where_ the checkbox is located, or the currently active cell _when_ the checkbox is clicked?

Comment: Where the checkbox is located, because active cell may not work if the active cell isnt the same as the clicked on checkbox.

Comment: What kind of checkbox are we talking about here? ActiveX or Forms?

Comment: A standard form, so not activeX

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Application.Caller is a String (the name of the control) not an Object, and the checkbox doesn't have a row property. You need to use:

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell.Row
```

for example.

Comment: Application.Caller is not always a string. It depends on the type of the caller...